# Escaping declaration | tumblr theme operators

Tags: sass, tumblr

I would like to use the [tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#get_started) theme operators in my output CSS.

So in my SCSS file I have something like the below.

```
article * img {
 max-width: 100%;
 {block:PermalinkPage}
  if is permalink page do this.
  min-width: 100;
 {/block:PermalinkPage}
}
```

So the question is can you tell SASS to not compile or ignore a certain section. Say by wrapping it in special characters and output as-is?

```
article * img {
 max-width: 100%;
 \{block:PermalinkPage}\
  if is permalink page do this.
  min-width: 100;
 \{/block:PermalinkPage}\
}
```

Comment: You can leave comments in using `/*! */`, but I'm not sure about properties...

Comment: I had thought about commenting it out, then un-commenting once compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no builtin way to ignore or not compile a line or section.

Here's a response to a [similar request](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/918):

> There's certainly not going to be a feature to just not parse a
>   section of the document

It has to be valid CSS/SCSS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's s shame they don't want to support this feature.